# Encryption error after upgrading mule from 3.8 to 3.9

Tags: exception, encryption, mule, runtime, public-key-encryption

Have anyone got below error, Please help.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.security.encryption.MuleEncryptionException: Could not encrypt the data
```

This never got while using mule version 3.8,
but started getting after upgrading to mule 3.9.

Comment: Please provide the complete error message including the full stack trace of the error, the Mule configuration and an explanation of what is the flow expected to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using new encryption connector configuration.